# C# Using Shutdown.exe just Shutdown

Tags: c#, shutdown

am using Shutdown.exe in my application because it offers some nice features like it can delay a shutdown and add a comment why need to shutdown.

The app specs can Shutdown, Restart, Log-Off, Hibernate, the Hybrid shutdown stuff, add comment, and delay a shutdown, and abort a scheduled shutdown.

The application was nice and dandy and I have made a setup file. I now tried installing it locally and used it. But when I tried for example clicked hybernate, it just shutdown ... I clicked on restart, it shuts down, and same thing with others.

I am pretty sure that I am using the correct combination of paramaters

this is the parameter I used

```
void PowerButtonsClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string p = string.Empty;

    if (sender == btnShutdown)
    {
        p += "-s";
    }
    else if (sender == btnRestart)
    {
        p += "-r";
    }
    else if (sender == btnSignoff)
    {
        p += "-l";
    }
    else if (sender == btnHibernate)
    {
        p += "-h";
    }
    else if (sender == btnHybridShutdown)
    {
        p += "-hybrid -s";
    }
    else if (sender == btnAbortShutdown)
    {
        p += "-a";
    }

    if (sender != btnAbortShutdown)
    {
        if (sender != btnSignoff || sender != btnHibernate)
        {
            if (isForced) { p += " -f"; }

            double seconds = TimeSpan.FromTicks(timePicker.Value.Value.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Ticks).TotalSeconds;

            p += " -t " + Convert.ToInt32(seconds);

            if (hasComment)
            {
                p += string.Format(" -c \"{0}\"", borderComment_txComment.Text);
            }
        }
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("param: " + p);

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        Arguments = p,
        FileName = "shutdown.exe"
    });
}
```

and this is the application I created 3 days ago. It was meant for Windows 8, and now, I shut off the download link because of the problem
http://wall.jaysonragasa.net/wall/post/2012/06/17/Windows-8-System-Power-Shortcuts.aspx

to tell you honestly, everything works well when running from IDE.. but when installed .. I had the problem. I even tried to disassemble the deployed application using ILSpy and it looks ok and nothing wrong..

-- UPDATE --
just to update my code in

```
if (sender != btnSignoff || sender != btnHibernate) { ~~ }
```

it must be

```
if (sender != btnSignoff && sender != btnHibernate) { ~~ }
```

the log result in case you requested

```
param: -s -f -t 0
param: -l
param: -r -f -t 0
param: -h
param: -a
param: -hybrid -s -f -t 0
param: -s -f -t 0 -c "my comment"
param: -s -f -t 5 -c "my comment"
param: -s -f -t 12118 -c "my comment"
param: -s -t 12110 -c "my comment"
```

-- UPDATE --

I have decided to use API calls but I loose the Abort functionality which is so important. If you can share how to Abort a scheduled shutdown, even if using WMI or API, kindly please share it.

Regards to all

Comment: Can you post your code showing how you're calling the exe with parameters?

Comment: Most of the `shutdown` command line options are not available on all Windows systems; for instance the `/a` (abort) option is only supported from Windows Server 2003 onwards IIRC. Maybe you're deploying your application on an older OS (2000, XP)?

Comment: Hi Frederic and Chris - First of all, before I started the app. I tested it using the command console and I'm using Windows 7 and Windows 8 - this is the application I have created
<br/>
http://wall.jaysonragasa.net/wall/post/2012/06/17/Windows-8-System-Power-Shortcuts.aspx

Comment: @JaysonRagasa Can you post the specific code you are using to use the shutdown features? I'm sure we can fix the issue once we see what you are using. From what I can see in the link the source code isn't available, and it should be posted in your question in the first place.

Comment: post updated - check the code

Comment: Can you get the app to log out to disk/console instead of calling the executable and posting the results. It would be easier to see what is going on

Comment: I have a feeling that it's down to permissions (or lack-off when calling the diagnostics process)

Comment: I tried running the deployed app as Administrator but am not sure it behaves the same thing. I click on abort .. it shutsdown, even if the parameter -a is correct

Comment: I have decided to use API calls but I loose the Abort functionality which is so important. If you can share how to Abort a scheduled shutdown, even if using WMI or API, kindly please share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this before and it may work for you:

```
    private void ShutdownComputer(bool restart)
    {
        ManagementBaseObject mboShutdown = null;
        ManagementClass mcWin32 = new ManagementClass("Win32_OperatingSystem");
        mcWin32.Get();        // You can't shutdown without security privileges
        mcWin32.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
        ManagementBaseObject mboShutdownParams = mcWin32.GetMethodParameters("Win32Shutdown");

        // Flag 1 means we want to shut down the system. Use "2" to reboot.
        mboShutdownParams["Flags"] = restart ? "2" : "1";
        mboShutdownParams["Reserved"] = "0";
        foreach (ManagementObject manObj in mcWin32.GetInstances())
        {
            mboShutdown = manObj.InvokeMethod("Win32Shutdown", mboShutdownParams, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was planning to go to API, but if that API call needs some elevated control, then I may resort to this. Thanks for sharing though, I keeping this

Comment: Do you have a way to make Abort a scheduled shutdown in WMI?